# MongoDB aggregation pipeline $project

Tags: mongodb, pandas, dataframe, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I'm using pymongo to extract data from a mongo database. Is it possible for me to alias the projected column names in any way. I'd like to return a dict that contains the keys "date", "daysworn", & "item"

```
pipeline =  [{ "$match": { "name": "Jack Jones",                                   
                       "date": {
                                "$gt": dt(2015,12,31,00,00),
                                "$lt": dt(2016,06,01,00,00)
                                }
                     }
          },
         {"$sort": SON(
                      [
                       ("date", 1), 
                       ("person.clothes.itemId", 1)
                       ]
                      )
          },
          {"$project": {
                        "date": 1,
                        "person.clothes.daysworn": 1,
                        "person.clothes.name": 1,
                        "_id":0
                        }
           }
         ]

cleanliness = people.aggregate(pipeline, allowDiskUse=True)
```

Is it possible for me to alias the projected column names in any way. I'd like to return a dict that contains the keys "date", "daysworn", & "item"

Comment: Yes, change the `$project` pipeline to `{"$project": {
                        "date": 1,
                        "daysworn": "$person.clothes.daysworn",
                        "name": "$person.clothes.name",
                        "_id":0
                        }
           }`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. Could you, for my edification, point out where it shows this in the documentation. I still can't find it mentioned any where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline to

```
{
    "$project": { 
        "date": 1, 
        "daysworn": "$person.clothes.daysworn", 
        "name": "$person.clothes.name", 
        "_id": 0 
    } 
}
```

The project operator is similar to `SELECT` in `SQL`. You can use this to rename the field names and select/deselect the fields to be returned or even flatten the data using project as shown in the example above by resetting the values of existing fields. More in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)